# Need help for generating the GEO trust certificate

Tags: ssl, keystore, keytool

When a security scan is done, we got the a violation mentioned as **SSL Weak Cipher Suite Encryption Algorithm Key Length Supported**. The resolution suggested is "Disable cipher suites that support less than a 128-bit encryption algorithm key length. Reconfigure the affected application to use a high-grade encryption cipher suite". We are using the following command to generate the CSR which is used as input for generating the GEO trust certificate. Can you please help us get the issue sorted out.

```
keytool -genkey -alias confluence-a -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keysize 2048 -keypass ******* -storepass '*****' -keystore /home/confluence-a.keystore

keytool -keystore /home/confluence-a.keystore -certreq -alias confluence-a -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keysize 2048 -keypass ****** -storepass '******' -file /home/confluence-a.csr
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. The key used by the cipher suite has nothing to do with the certificate. You need to look at the API for `SSLSocket` and friends.